# How to pass JAAS configuration kafka env variables kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am trying to authenticate my Kafka rest proxy with SASL but I am having trouble transferring the configs made in my local docker compose to Kubernetes.

I am using JAAS configuration to achieve this.
My JAAS file looks like this.

```
KafkaClient {
       org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
       username="rest"
       password="rest-secret";
};

Client {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       username="rest"
       password="restsecret";
};
```

and then in my docker compose I have done:

`KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/rest_jaas.conf`

How will I transfer this same logic to Kubernetes?
I have tried passing the env variable like this:

```
env:
  - name: KAFKA_OPTS
    value: |
      KafkaClient {
        org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
        username="rest"
        password="rest-secret";
      };
      Client {
        org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
        username="rest"
        password="rest-secret";
      };
```

but it still fails. Here is what my logs say:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class KafkaClient
/bin/sh: 3: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule: not found
/bin/sh: 6: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save your Kafka JAAS config file as rest_jaas.conf. Then execute:

```
kubectl create secret generic kafka-secret --from-file=rest_jaas.conf
```

Then in your deployment you insert:

```
      env:
      - name: KAFKA_OPTS 
        value: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/rest_jaas.conf
      volumeMounts:
      - name: kafka-secret
        mountPath: /etc/kafka/secrets
        subPath: rest_jaas.conf
    volumes:
    - name: kafka-secret
      secret:
        secretName: kafka-secret
```

Comment: Does KAFKA_OPTS only allow for file contents? can't it be configured any other way other than getting the configs from the file?

Comment: KAFKA_OPTS is environment variable. It can store string of very limited length (i don't know maximum length). So it is better if you store configs as files.

Comment: @VasiliAngapov: I am using same format rest_jaas.conf but getting below exception.
java.io.EOFException: null